# Creating nested dictionary from text file

Tags: python

```
/tmp/bond0:

Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2+3 (2)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
Active Aggregator Info:
Aggregator ID: 2
Number of ports: 2
Actor Key: 11
Partner Key: 705
Partner Mac Address: 02:1c:73:9c:3c:fe

Slave Interface: p1p1
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 9c:dc:71:45:eb:80
Aggregator ID: 2
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: p4p1
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 9c:dc:71:4d:80:20
Aggregator ID: 2
Slave queue ID: 0
```

I have the above text outputs and I want to create a nested dictionary that looks like this:
in the text above there could be more than two slave interface blocks

```
bond0 : {
 'MII Status:' : 'up',
 'Aggregator ID:' : '2',
 'Slave Interfaces' : { 'p1p1' : { 'MII Status' : 'up',
 'Permanent HW addr' : '9c:dc:71:45:eb:80',
 'MII Status' : up },
 'p4p1' : { ''MII Status' : 'up',
 'Permanent HW addr' : '9c:dc:71:4d:80:20',
 'MII Status' : up },
 },
```

I began doing some coding as shown below, but still not getting there :
   #/usr/bin/python

from **future** import print_function
   import pprint
   import os
   import re
   import subprocess

```
class BndClass(dict):
   def __init__(self, Bnd=None):
      self['Name'] = Bnd
      self.uPdateInfo()
      super(BndClass, self).__init__()

   def uPdateInfo(self):
      OutBnd = subprocess.Popen(['cat', '/tmp/'\
    + self['Name']],shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      for line in OutBnd.stdout:
          match = re.search(r'^Cur.*?:\s+(.*?)$', line)
          if match:
              self['act_int'] = match.group(1)

          match = re.search(r'^\s*?Aggregator ID:\s+(\d)$', line)
          if match:
              self['agid'] = match.group(1)

          match = re.search(r'^Slave\sInterface:\s(.*?)$', line)
          if match:
              self.setdefault('slvs', []).append(match.group(1))


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      Y = BndClass('bond0')

  Y:

  {'Name': 'bond0', 'agid': '2', 'slvs': ['p1p1', 'p4p1']}
```

---

I may have many more 'bond' files viz bond1,2,3,4 so on..so I thought it make more sense to have class and I converted to a class form. However it fails. Any thoughts?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint
import os
import re
import subprocess



class BndClass(dict):
    def __init__(self, Bnd=None):
        self['Name'] = Bnd
        self.uPdateInfo()
        super(BndClass, self).__init__()

    def uPdateInfo(self):
        with open(self['Name'], "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()  # clean that up a bit :)
                if line.strip() == "": continue
                match = re.search(r'^\s*?(Aggregator ID):\s+(\d)$', line)
                if match:
                    self[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
                    continue

                match = re.search(r'^(Slave\sInterface):\s(.*?)$', line)
                if match:
                    self[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
                    while True:
                        try:
                            line = next(f).strip()
                        except:
                            break
                        if line == "":
                            break
                        slave_match = re.search(r'^(MII\sStatus):\s+(\w+)$', line)
                        if slave_match:
                            self.setdefault(match.group(1), {}).setdefault(match.group(2), {})[slave_match.group(1)] = slave_match.group(2)
                            continue
                        slave_match = re.search(r'^(Permanent\sHW\saddr):\s+(.+)$', line)
                        if slave_match:
                            self.setdefault(match.group(1), {}).setdefault(match.group(2), {})[slave_match.group(1)] = slave_match.group(2)
                            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
   B = BndClass('bond0')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./bc6.py", line 47, in <module>
    B = BndClass('bond0')
 File "./bc6.py", line 14, in __init__
   self.uPdateInfo()
 File "./bc6.py", line 39, in uPdateInfo
   self.setdefault(match.group(1), {}).setdefault(match.group(2), {}) 
 [slave_match.group(1)] = slave_match.group(2)
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

Comment: You forgot the `code` balise for the dict you want and the last line. (I cannot edit them since "its mostly code")

Comment: You did not provide a working minimal example, it's fine by me since It's fairly well explained but in the future you should remove some parts for a smaller example. For instance, removing the class which is not usefull for use and providing a dummy file rather than a complete one (it's annoying to write regex ^^)

I'm on it tho

Comment: sorry. Will be diligent next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with below solution, which might do what I want. Thanks

```
import re
import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

class AclassOfItwsOwn():
    def __init__(self, bond):
    self.bond = bond


def doIt(self):
    return self.MakeDict(self.bond)

@staticmethod
def MakeDict(bond):
    final_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str))

    with open(bond + '.txt', "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.strip() == "":
                continue
            match = re.search(r'^\s*?(Aggregator ID):\s+(\d)$', line)
            if match:
                final_dict[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
                continue

            match = re.search(r'^(Slave\sInterface):\s(.*?)$', line)
            if match:
                final_dict[match.group(1)][match.group(2)] = {}
                while True:
                    try:
                        line = next(f).strip()
                    except:
                        break
                    if line == "":
                        break
                    slave_match = re.search(r'^(MII\sStatus):\s+(\w+)$', line)
                    if slave_match:
                        final_dict[match.group(1)][match.group(2)][slave_match.group(1)] = slave_match.group(2)
                        continue
                    slave_match = re.search(r'^(Permanent\sHW\saddr):\s+(.+)$', line)
                    if slave_match:
                        final_dict[match.group(1)][match.group(2)][slave_match.group(1)] = slave_match.group(2)
                        continue
    return final_dict

b0 = AclassOfItwsOwn('bond0')
b0.doIt()
b2 = AclassOfItwsOwn('bond2')
b2.doIt()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I started and then I did something else and forgot...

Here's a solution, it's not the sexiest but it's working nonetheless. If your file have a very strict formatting (as it appears to be) you can be more efficient with the `break` and `continue` statements to avoid useless regex searches.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

final_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str))

with open("bound0_file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()  # clean that up a bit :)
        if line.strip() == "": continue
        match = re.search(r'^\s*?(Aggregator ID):\s+(\d)$', line)
        if match:
            final_dict[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
            continue

        match = re.search(r'^(Slave\sInterface):\s(.*?)$', line)
        if match:
            final_dict[match.group(1)][match.group(2)] = {}
            while True:
                try:
                    line = next(f).strip()
                except:
                    break
                if line == "":
                    break
                slave_match = re.search(r'^(MII\sStatus):\s+(\w+)$', line)
                if slave_match:
                    final_dict[match.group(1)][match.group(2)][slave_match.group(1)] = slave_match.group(2)
                    continue
                slave_match = re.search(r'^(Permanent\sHW\saddr):\s+(.+)$', line)
                if slave_match:
                    final_dict[match.group(1)][match.group(2)][slave_match.group(1)] = slave_match.group(2)
                    continue

    print(final_dict)
```

---

```
from collections import defaultdict
final_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str))
```

Here we use a `defaultdict` which will allow us to "create key on request", basically if you search for a key that does not exists `defaultdict` will create it instead of raising an error.

I'm nesting two of them because the one I really want is the second one and because you have at most 2 levels.

```
...
match = re.search(r'^\s*?(Aggregator ID):\s+(\d)$', line)
if match:
        final_dict[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
        continue
```

Here it's pretty explanatory, if my line is the **aggregator id** one I just put that in my `final_dict`. **Notice the added group around "aggregator id)**. Then, because I know I'm done with this line I use a `continue` statement to skip the rest of the loop and proceed to the next line.

```
...
match = re.search(r'^(Slave\sInterface):\s(.*?)$', line)
if match:
    final_dict[match.group(1)][match.group(2)] = {}
```

Here start the tricky part. If the previous `match` failed (aka line not **aggregator id**) then we try this one, if it's not the **slave interface** we just loop over the next line.

However if it's this line, that means we enter a *slave interface block* that will end with an empty line (see a bit later).

This `final_dict` line is why I had to use `defaultdict`, because I will be creating the nested dict `Slave interface: { 'p1p1': {} }` immediatly.

```
        ...
        while True:
            try:
                line = next(f).strip()
            except:
                break
```

We enter a "sub-loop" I'm using to go through the *slave interface block* to look for the entries you want (**MII Status** and **Permanent HW addr**). We're going to do some stuff in this sub-loop (below) but when we find an empty line, that means we are done with the current block. (The try-expect statement is here to `break` out if we reach end of file).

```
            ...
            if slave_match:
                final_dict[match.group(1)][match.group(2)][slave_match.group(1)] = slave_match.group(2)
                continue
            slave_match = re.search(r'^(Permanent\sHW\saddr):\s+(.+)$', line)
            if slave_match:
                final_dict[match.group(1)][match.group(2)][slave_match.group(1)] = slave_match.group(2)
                continue
```

This is exactly the same thing as the first `match`, we look for the right line and add it to the `final_dict`. However we need to use another variable since we need the `match` one to access the right position in our dict.

---

As you can see you were really close by yourself. This method may not be the best one though.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes the tricky part was while loop and it didn't strike me that is how you process slave block. Much appreciated.